# Python Flask, displaying an input from one page on another

Tags: python, function, flask, input

None of the other answers on this seem to solve my problem. I am trying to display a greeting that says "Welcome to the app [user]" when someone logs in. I am not sure how to get the `greet` page to display this message.

Here is my login function

```
@app.route("/login2", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session.permanent = True
        user=request.form["nm"]
        session["user"] = user 
        return render_template("greet.html")
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("greet"))
        return render_template("login2.html")
```

Here is my login.html page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log In Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}    
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                <p>{{msg}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}



    <form action="#" method="post"> 
        <p>Name: </p>
        <p><input type="text", name="nm" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit", value="submit" /></p> 

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is greet.html, which should display the message that I want.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} <h1>Welcome</h1> 
<p>Hi, Welcome to the app {{}} .</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I believe that I need to pass something into the {{}} on the greet.html page, but I do not know what to pass in here.

Answer (score 1):

In your login route when the method is POST pass the user object to the template.

```
@app.route("/login2", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session.permanent = True
        user=request.form["nm"]
        session["user"] = user 
        return render_template("greet.html", user=user)
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("greet"))
        return render_template("login2.html")
```

Now you can use it in the template

```
<p>Hi, Welcome to the app {{user.name}} .</p>
```

Comment: Good that you got it working. I'm not really sure why it was down voted. Probably you have to specify what error you are getting. Do not hesitate to keep asking questions, this is the purpose of stackoverflow, just read the guidelines.